# Stretchy Header with UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint, stretch, snapkit

My problem seems obvious and duplicated but I can't manage to make it work.

I'm trying to achieve the famous stretchy header effect (image's top side stuck to top of `UIScrollView` when scrolling), but with an `UIPageViewController` instead of simply an image.

My structure is:

```
UINavigationBar
   |-- UIScrollView
         |-- UIView (totally optional container)
              |-- UIPageViewController (as UIView, embedded with addChild()) <-- TO STICK
              |-- UIHostingViewController (SwiftUI view with labels, also embedded)
              |-- UITableView (not embedded but could be)
```

My `UIPageViewController` contains images to make a carousel, nothing more.
All my views are laid out with `NSLayoutConstraint`s (with visual format for vertical layout in the container).

I trie sticking `topAnchor` of the page controller's view to the one of `self.view` (with or without `priority`) but no luck, and no matter what I do it changes absolutely nothing.

I finally tried to use `SnapKit` but it doesn't work neither (I don't know much about it but it seems to only be a wrapper for `NSLayoutConstaint`s so I'm not surprised it doesn't work too).

I followed [this tutorial](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-make-a-stretchy-header-in-ios-using-swift/), [this one](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tutorial-creating-stretchy-layouts-on-ios-using-auto-layout-3fa974fa5e28/) and [that one](https://medium.com/fantageek/stretchy-header-with-auto-layout-in-ios-5cd5e16e3f7f) but none of them worked.

(How) can I achieve what I want?

**EDIT 1:**
To clarify, my carousel currently has a forced height of 350. I want to achieve this exact effect (that is shown with a single `UIImageView`) on my whole carousel:

[image: gif]

To clarify as much as possible, I want to replicate this effect to my whole `UIPageViewController`/carousel so that the displayed page/image can have this effect when scrolled.

**NOTE:** as mentioned in the structure above, I have a (transparent) navigation bar, and **my safe area insets are respected (nothing goes under the status bar)**. I don't think it would change the solution (as the solution is probably a way to stick the top of the carousel to `self.view`, no matter the frame of `self.view`) but I prefer you to know everything.

**EDIT 2:**
Main VC with @DonMag's answer:

```swift
    private let info: UITableView = {
        let v = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .insetGrouped)
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    private lazy var infoHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        // Needed constraint because else standalone UITableView gets an height of 0 even with usual constraints
        // I update this constraint in viewWillAppear & viewDidAppear when the table gets a proper contentSize
        info.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
    }()
    
    private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

        // MARK: Views declaration
        // Container for carousel
        let stretchyView = UIView()
        stretchyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // Carousel
        let carouselController = ProfileDetailCarousel(images: [
            UIImage(named: "1")!,
            UIImage(named: "2")!,
            UIImage(named: "3")!,
            UIImage(named: "4")!
        ])
        addChild(carouselController)
        let carousel: UIView = carouselController.view
        carousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stretchyView.addSubview(carousel)
        carouselController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        // Container for below-carousel views
        let contentView = UIView()
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // Texts and bio
        let bioController = UIHostingController(rootView: ProfileDetailBio())
        addChild(bioController)
        let bio: UIView = bioController.view
        bio.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(bio)
        bioController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        // Info table
        info.delegate = tableDelegate
        info.dataSource = tableDataSource
        tableDelegate.viewController = self
        contentView.addSubview(info)
        
        [stretchyView, contentView].forEach { v in
            scrollView.addSubview(v)
        }
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // MARK: Constraints
        let stretchyTop = stretchyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        stretchyTop.priority = .defaultHigh
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // Scroll view
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            
            // Stretchy view
            stretchyTop,
            
            stretchyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            stretchyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            stretchyView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 350.0),
            
            // Carousel
            carousel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.topAnchor),
            carousel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.bottomAnchor),
            carousel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.centerXAnchor),
            carousel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.widthAnchor),
            
            // Content view
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 350.0),
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.bottomAnchor),
            
            // Bio
            bio.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0),
            bio.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            bio.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            bio.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            
            // Info table
            info.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bio.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            info.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            info.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            infoHeightConstraint
        ])
    }
```

Comment: Your view hierarchy is not-quite-right. To clarify... do you want your Page View Controller to have a **minimum** height? Or, do you want it to "squeeze out of existence"? If a min height, do you want the scrolling content to slide under it or over it?

Comment: OK - you want the Page View Controller to **stretch** when you pull down, then snap back to original height when touch is released.... when scrolling up, you just want it "pushed off the screen" - not "squeezed" vertically? And, in the gif you show , the image Height (where you want your page view) is much less than 350-points?

Comment: @DonMag yes. I want it to stretch when I pull down (as post title + gif) and snap back to original height when touch is released OR when scroll view is pulled up again. Then when scrolling up (`scrollView.contentOffset.y` > 0), the behavior stays natural, which means that the carousel keeps its "creation height" and it's pushed off the screen as a normal `UIScrollView` subview.
The special behavior I'm asking for only applies when `scrollView.contentOffset.y` < 0.
Concerning the gif, I've taken it from the 2nd tutorial I linked, it's not my code. It's here only to show the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view hierarchy should be:

```
UINavigationBar
   |-- UIScrollView
         |-- UIView ("stretchy" container view)
              |-- UIPageViewController (as UIView, embedded with asChild())
         |-- UIHostingViewController (SwiftUI view with labels, also embedded)
```

To get the stretchy view to "stick to the top":

We constrain the stretchy view's Top to the scroll view's `.frameLayoutGuide` Top, but we give that constraint a less-than-required `.priority` so we can "push it" up and off the screen.

We also give the stretchy view a Height constraint of greater-than-or-equal-to 350. This will allow it to stretch - but not compress - vertically.

We'll call the view from the `UIHostingViewController` our "contentView" ... and we'll constrain its Top to the stretchy view's Bottom.

Then, we give the content view *another* Top constraint -- this time to the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide`, with a constant of 350 (the height of the stretchy view). This, plus the Leading/Trailing/Bottom constraints defines the "scrollable area."

When we scroll (pull) down, the content view will "pull down" the Bottom of the stretchy view.

When we scroll (push) up, the content view will "push up" the entire stretchy view.

Here's how it looks (too big to add as a gif here): https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wvxK.jpg

And here's the sample code to make that. Everything is done via code, so no `@IBOutlet` or other connections needed. Also note that I used three images for the page views - "ex1", "ex2", "ex3":

**View Controller**

```
class StretchyHeaderViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        return v
    }()
    let stretchyView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        return v
    }()
    let contentView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return v
    }()
    
    let stretchyViewHeight: CGFloat = 350.0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set to a greter-than-zero value if you want spacing between the "pages"
        let opts = [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey.interPageSpacing: 0.0]
        // instantiate the Page View controller
        let pgVC = SamplePageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: opts)
        // add it as a child controller
        self.addChild(pgVC)
        // safe unwrap
        guard let pgv = pgVC.view else { return }
        pgv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // add the page controller view to stretchyView
        stretchyView.addSubview(pgv)
        pgVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain page view controller's view on all 4 sides
            pgv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.topAnchor),
            pgv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.bottomAnchor),
            pgv.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.centerXAnchor),
            pgv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.widthAnchor),
        ])
        
        [scrollView, stretchyView, contentView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // add contentView and stretchyView to the scroll view
        [stretchyView, contentView].forEach { v in
            scrollView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        // add scroll view to self.view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        // keep stretchyView's Top "pinned" to the Top of the scroll view FRAME
        //  so its Height will "stretch" when scroll view is pulled down
        let stretchyTop = stretchyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        // priority needs to be less-than-required so we can "push it up" out of view
        stretchyTop.priority = .defaultHigh
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // scroll view Top to view Top
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // scroll view Leading/Trailing/Bottom to safe area
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // constrain stretchy view Top to scroll view's FRAME
            stretchyTop,
            
            // stretchyView to Leading/Trailing of scroll view FRAME
            stretchyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stretchyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // stretchyView Height - greater-than-or-equal-to
            //  so it can "stretch" vertically
            stretchyView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: stretchyViewHeight),
            
            // content view Leading/Trailing/Bottom to scroll view's CONTENT GUIDE
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // content view Width to scroll view's FRAME
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // content view Top to scroll view's CONTENT GUIDE
            //  plus Height of stretchyView
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: stretchyViewHeight),

            // content view Top to stretchyView Bottom
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stretchyView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
    
        ])
        
        // add some content to the content view so we have something to scroll
        addSomeContent()
                
    }
    
    func addSomeContent() {
        // vertical stack view with 20 labels
        //  so we have something to scroll
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.spacing = 32
        stack.backgroundColor = .gray
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        for i in 1...20 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48.0).isActive = true
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        contentView.addSubview(stack)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

**Controller for each Page**

```
class OnePageVC: UIViewController {
    
    var image: UIImage = UIImage() {
        didSet {
            imgView.image = image
        }
    }
    let imgView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        v.clipsToBounds = true
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain image view to all 4 sides
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
    }
}
```

**Sample Page View Controller**

```
class SamplePageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    
    var controllers: [UIViewController] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let imgNames: [String] = [
            "ex1", "ex2", "ex3",
        ]
        for i in 0..<imgNames.count {
            let aViewController = OnePageVC()
            if let img = UIImage(named: imgNames[i]) {
                aViewController.image = img
            }
            self.controllers.append(aViewController)
        }

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        
        self.setViewControllers([controllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false)
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), index > 0 {
            return controllers[index - 1]
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), index < controllers.count - 1 {
            return controllers[index + 1]
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**

Looking at the code you posted in your question's Edit... it's a little tough, since I don't know what your `ProfileDetailBio` view is, but here are a couple tips to help debug this type of situation during development:

- give your views contrasting background colors... makes it easy to see the frames when you run the app
- if a subview fills its superview's width, make it a little narrower so you can see what's "behind / under" it
- set `.clipsToBounds = true` on views you're using as "containers" - such as `contentView`... if a subview is then "missing" you know it has extended outside the bounds of the container

So, for your code...

```
// so we can see the contentView frame
contentView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow

// leave some space on the right-side of bio view, so we
//   so we can see the contentView behind it
bio.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -100.0),
```

If you run the app, you will likely see that `contentView` only extends to the bottom of `bio` - not to the bottom of `info`.

If you then do this:

```
contentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

`info` will likely not be visible at all.

Checking your constraints, you have:

```
bio.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        
// Info table
info.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bio.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
```

where it should be:

```
// no bio bottom anchor
//bio.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),

// this is correct
// Info table
info.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bio.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),

// add this
info.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
```

Run the app, and you *should* now again see `info`, and `contentView` extends to the bottom of `info`.

Assuming `bio` and `info` height combined are tall enough to require scrolling, you can undo the "debug / dev" changes and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for you **amazing** answer! First of all, yeah I forgot to mention I do everything programmatically (never used `@IBOutlet` and likely never will), so this answer is perfect.
However, everything lays out perfectly but I can't scroll **at all** my `UIScrollView`. I copied everything you did but no luck. Carousel is scrollable but not main page (not up neither down). I updated my post with my result, can you take a look please?

Comment: @Arainty - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, fixing the constraints with your last block of code did the trick!! (I still don't quite get why this prevented the scroll view to scroll, but nvm).
Some last points: 1) `ProfileDetailBio` is a SwiftUI view containing a few labels layer out much easier than in pure Swift, thanks to declarative programming 2) I already used to use red/blue bg to debug, thanks anyway! 3) your potential fix to avoid using my `infoHeightConstraint` didn't work, I added it back in `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` in addition to your last block of code

Comment: 4) do you know why my scrollView can't get "higher" than my navigation bar (my carousel isn't _also_ under status bar as yours)? Is it a normal behavior when a controller is embedded in an `UINavigationController`? 5) would you know how to remove the sort of black/white background to iPhone X homebar at the very bottom that we both have? 6) do we agree that specifying `, constant: 0.0` isn't required at all when you don't need to modify this constant later on? I removed them. - Lastly, thanks again for your help, it was comprehensive, clear and the result looks absolutely stunning!!

Comment: @Arainty - the constraint from `contentView.bottomAnchor` to `scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` defines the "scrollable area" ... when you add `info` but allow it to extend *below the bottom of `contentView`* it's not adding any height to the scrollable area... so no scrolling.

Comment: @Arainty - **3)** sorry, I was just showing the relevant lines... `info.leadingAnchor` / `info.trailingAnchor` / `infoHeightConstraint` should still be there. **4)** not sure what you mean - show a screen-shot or two? **5)** I guess you mean what you get by constraining scroll view bottom to `view.bottomAnchor`  instead of `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor`? We should always respect the safe area though, but it's your app. **6)** `constant: 0.0` isn't needed, whether it will be modified or not. I just tend to always include it for consistency.

Comment: 3) yes they are still there on my side too 4) here is how it looks for me: https://imgur.com/a/W7xr3cp ; yours goes below status bar too. It works like a charm but I was just wondering why yours goes higher than me. because of navbar? 5) I agree about the safe area thing, but I can take as an example the Settings app that doesn't have this little background and is an Apple app... anyway I already tried `view.bottomAnchor` but it doesn't change anything 6) okay thanks for the tip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243905/discussion-between-arainty-and-donmag).